# Value if term equals previous term count plus value

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I calculate the value of the term in a range like this:

1:0
2:1
3:3
4:6
5:10
...

As you can see the value of any given term is equal to the value of the previous term plus the identifier of the previous term, but I have no idea what the formula would be for calculating the value of any given term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At identifier $n$ the value is $n(n-1)/2$. You can show this by induction from $f(n+1)=n+f(n).$